# what happens to http request when route changes in SPA

Tags: php, node.js, angular, reactjs, single-page-application

lets imagine that a **request is loading** and the page(component) changes what happens to the request that is loading ?

please consider that it is in case of using **front-End SPA**(single page application) such as projects with **angular.js,angular,react** and others .. &&

and what will happen in **back-End** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are some options depending on the request library that you are using. But as you said, it is a single page app and you can take the event of unmounting that page or component.

Example:

Using react, one of the lifecycle methods is ComponentWillUnmount, imagine that you send a request in ComponentDidMount and before the request finishes user leaves the page. You can cancel the request in **ComponentWillUnmount**.

You can cancel requests using almost all http libraries, in particular redux-obseravble with rxjs is a really good option.

```
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';

const fetchUserEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(FETCH_USER),
  mergeMap(action => ajax.getJSON(`/api/users/${action.payload}`).pipe(
    map(response => fetchUserFulfilled(response)),
    takeUntil(action$.pipe(
      ofType(FETCH_USER_CANCELLED)
    ))
  ))
);
```

When user press a button or when you load the page you can launch an action to fetch user data, until it finishes or an action of fetch_user_cancelled is launched, for example, in componentWillUnmount.

I hope to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Once a request has been fired from the SPA, it will remain open until response from backend is obtained or the connection is terminated. Termination can happen in multiple ways such as :

- Page reload.
- Manual termination using the clientreq object.